# How do I reduce the space below my element/text using padding/margin?

Tags: html, css

[my website learning](http://port-80-3rebi65pw2.treehouse-app.com/)

Hi everybody.

Im martin.

So im learning to use html and CSS but i'm running through some trouble. 
if you are able to see my website (practice) that im trying to create, i wish to reduce the space under the word 'I am ______| learner' and under 'contact'.
I have tried to using padding-bottom but i must be doing something wrong, and i have been playing around for way way too long to understand padding,margins and borders but my head is so confused right now!

Thank you everyone!

```
/****************************
CSS
*****************************/

#wrapper {
  margin:15% auto;
  padding:5px;
  max-width:1024px;
}
body {
  color:#988;
  background:white;
  font-family: 'oswald', monospace;
}

/****************************
LOGO/HEADING
****************************/
header {
  background:#a0a0a0;
}

#logo {
  text-decoration:none;

}

h1 {
  font-family:'oswald', monospace;
  font-size:2em;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  margin:1px;
  padding:7px;
  line-height:0.8em;

}
nav {
  font-size:1em;
  background:#d0d0d0;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:0px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  padding-bottom:1px;
}


/****************************
nav a links
*****************************/

nav a, nav a:visited {
  color:#FFF;
}

nav a.selected, nav a:hover {
  color:#131c1f;
}
```

Comment: Hi Martin, you need to include the relevant code for the problem in the post itself - not a link to a 3rd party that will change or be unavailable over time. See how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Please do not sweat up where there is a will there's a way we are here to help you in all way.

All i came to know from your question is that you have an element suppose

I am

having border and you to reduce spacing between text "I am" and border correct?

well here is the suggestion. You just need to play using property "Padding-bottom".

in case it still not working and you want more space to be decreased you can also try line-height property. You can giver line-height property in px, em, or %.

I hope this suggestions works well for your problems.

Adios. Cheeers....

Answer (score 0):

you can use margin-top or margin-bottom

```css
/****************************
CSS
*****************************/

#wrapper {
  margin:15% auto;
  padding:5px;
  max-width:1024px;
}
body {
  color:#988;
  background:white;
  font-family: 'oswald', monospace;
}

/****************************
LOGO/HEADING
****************************/
header {
  background:#a0a0a0;
}

#logo {
  text-decoration:none;

}

h1 {
  font-family:'oswald', monospace;
  font-size:2em;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:20px;
 margin-bottom:20px;
  padding:7px;
  line-height:0.8em;

}
nav {
  font-size:1em;
  background:#d0d0d0;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:0px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  padding-bottom:1px;
}


/****************************
nav a links
*****************************/

nav a, nav a:visited {
  color:#FFF;
}

nav a.selected, nav a:hover {
  color:#131c1f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing the default top and bottom `margin` on the `ul` inside of `nav`. To remove that, just set `margin: 0` or change it to whatever value you want.

The top margin is "collapsing" so it shows outside of the parent. You can read more about that here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

```css
/* normalize */

/*! normalize.css v1.1.0 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */

/* ==========================================================================
   HTML5 display definitions
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Correct `block` display not defined in IE 6/7/8/9 and Firefox 3.
 */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
nav,
section,
summary {
    display: block;
}

/**
 * Correct `inline-block` display not defined in IE 6/7/8/9 and Firefox 3.
 */

audio,
canvas,
video {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
}

/**
 * Prevent modern browsers from displaying `audio` without controls.
 * Remove excess height in iOS 5 devices.
 */

audio:not([controls]) {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
}

/**
 * Address styling not present in IE 7/8/9, Firefox 3, and Safari 4.
 * Known issue: no IE 6 support.
 */

[hidden] {
    display: none;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Base
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * 1. Correct text resizing oddly in IE 6/7 when body `font-size` is set using
 *    `em` units.
 * 2. Prevent iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling
 *    user zoom.
 */

html {
    font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Address `font-family` inconsistency between `textarea` and other form
 * elements.
 */

html,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

/**
 * Address margins handled incorrectly in IE 6/7.
 */

body {
    margin: 0;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Links
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Address `outline` inconsistency between Chrome and other browsers.
 */

a:focus {
    outline: thin dotted;
}

/**
 * Improve readability when focused and also mouse hovered in all browsers.
 */

a:active,
a:hover {
    outline: 0;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Typography
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Address font sizes and margins set differently in IE 6/7.
 * Address font sizes within `section` and `article` in Firefox 4+, Safari 5,
 * and Chrome.
 */

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0.67em 0;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 0.83em 0;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.17em;
    margin: 1em 0;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 1.33em 0;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 0.83em;
    margin: 1.67em 0;
}

h6 {
    font-size: 0.67em;
    margin: 2.33em 0;
}

/**
 * Address styling not present in IE 7/8/9, Safari 5, and Chrome.
 */

abbr[title] {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

/**
 * Address style set to `bolder` in Firefox 3+, Safari 4/5, and Chrome.
 */

b,
strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}

blockquote {
    margin: 1em 40px;
}

/**
 * Address styling not present in Safari 5 and Chrome.
 */

dfn {
    font-style: italic;
}

/**
 * Address differences between Firefox and other browsers.
 * Known issue: no IE 6/7 normalization.
 */

hr {
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 0;
}

/**
 * Address styling not present in IE 6/7/8/9.
 */

mark {
    background: #ff0;
    color: #000;
}

/**
 * Address margins set differently in IE 6/7.
 */

p,
pre {
    margin: 1em 0;
}

/**
 * Correct font family set oddly in IE 6, Safari 4/5, and Chrome.
 */

code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
    font-family: monospace, serif;
    _font-family: 'courier new', monospace;
    font-size: 1em;
}

/**
 * Improve readability of pre-formatted text in all browsers.
 */

pre {
    white-space: pre;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

/**
 * Address CSS quotes not supported in IE 6/7.
 */

q {
    quotes: none;
}

/**
 * Address `quotes` property not supported in Safari 4.
 */

q:before,
q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}

/**
 * Address inconsistent and variable font size in all browsers.
 */

small {
    font-size: 80%;
}

/**
 * Prevent `sub` and `sup` affecting `line-height` in all browsers.
 */

sub,
sup {
    font-size: 75%;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

sup {
    top: -0.5em;
}

sub {
    bottom: -0.25em;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Lists
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Address margins set differently in IE 6/7.
 */

dl,
menu,
ol,
ul {
    margin: 1em 0;
}

dd {
    margin: 0 0 0 40px;
}

/**
 * Address paddings set differently in IE 6/7.
 */

menu,
ol,
ul {
    padding: 0 0 0 40px;
}

/**
 * Correct list images handled incorrectly in IE 7.
 */

nav ul,
nav ol {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    margin: 0;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Embedded content
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * 1. Remove border when inside `a` element in IE 6/7/8/9 and Firefox 3.
 * 2. Improve image quality when scaled in IE 7.
 */

img {
    border: 0; /* 1 */
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Correct overflow displayed oddly in IE 9.
 */

svg:not(:root) {
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Figures
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Address margin not present in IE 6/7/8/9, Safari 5, and Opera 11.
 */

figure {
    margin: 0;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Forms
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Correct margin displayed oddly in IE 6/7.
 */

form {
    margin: 0;
}

/**
 * Define consistent border, margin, and padding.
 */

fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct color not being inherited in IE 6/7/8/9.
 * 2. Correct text not wrapping in Firefox 3.
 * 3. Correct alignment displayed oddly in IE 6/7.
 */

legend {
    border: 0; /* 1 */
    padding: 0;
    white-space: normal; /* 2 */
    *margin-left: -7px; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * 1. Correct font size not being inherited in all browsers.
 * 2. Address margins set differently in IE 6/7, Firefox 3+, Safari 5,
 *    and Chrome.
 * 3. Improve appearance and consistency in all browsers.
 */

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
    margin: 0; /* 2 */
    vertical-align: baseline; /* 3 */
    *vertical-align: middle; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * Address Firefox 3+ setting `line-height` on `input` using `!important` in
 * the UA stylesheet.
 */

button,
input {
    line-height: normal;
}

/**
 * Address inconsistent `text-transform` inheritance for `button` and `select`.
 * All other form control elements do not inherit `text-transform` values.
 * Correct `button` style inheritance in Chrome, Safari 5+, and IE 6+.
 * Correct `select` style inheritance in Firefox 4+ and Opera.
 */

button,
select {
    text-transform: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Avoid the WebKit bug in Android 4.0.* where (2) destroys native `audio`
 *    and `video` controls.
 * 2. Correct inability to style clickable `input` types in iOS.
 * 3. Improve usability and consistency of cursor style between image-type
 *    `input` and others.
 * 4. Remove inner spacing in IE 7 without affecting normal text inputs.
 *    Known issue: inner spacing remains in IE 6.
 */

button,
html input[type="button"], /* 1 */
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: button; /* 2 */
    cursor: pointer; /* 3 */
    *overflow: visible;  /* 4 */
}

/**
 * Re-set default cursor for disabled elements.
 */

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
    cursor: default;
}

/**
 * 1. Address box sizing set to content-box in IE 8/9.
 * 2. Remove excess padding in IE 8/9.
 * 3. Remove excess padding in IE 7.
 *    Known issue: excess padding remains in IE 6.
 */

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
    padding: 0; /* 2 */
    *height: 13px; /* 3 */
    *width: 13px; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * 1. Address `appearance` set to `searchfield` in Safari 5 and Chrome.
 * 2. Address `box-sizing` set to `border-box` in Safari 5 and Chrome
 *    (include `-moz` to future-proof).
 */

input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* 1 */
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; /* 2 */
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

/**
 * Remove inner padding and search cancel button in Safari 5 and Chrome
 * on OS X.
 */

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/**
 * Remove inner padding and border in Firefox 3+.
 */

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/**
 * 1. Remove default vertical scrollbar in IE 6/7/8/9.
 * 2. Improve readability and alignment in all browsers.
 */

textarea {
    overflow: auto; /* 1 */
    vertical-align: top; /* 2 */
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Tables
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove most spacing between table cells.
 */

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/* main.css */
/****************************
CSS
*****************************/

#wrapper {
  margin:15% auto;
  padding:5px;
  max-width:1024px;
}
body {
  color:#988;
  background:white;
  font-family: 'oswald', monospace;
}

/****************************
LOGO/HEADING
****************************/
header {
  background:#a0a0a0;
}

#logo {
  text-decoration:none;
 
}

h1 {
  font-family:'oswald', monospace;
  font-size:2em;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  margin:1px;
  padding:7px;
  line-height:0.8em;
  
}
nav {
  font-size:1em;
  background:#d0d0d0;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:0px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  padding-bottom:1px;
}


/****************************
nav a links
*****************************/

nav a, nav a:visited {
  color:#FFF;
}

nav a.selected, nav a:hover {
  color:#131c1f;
}

nav ul {
margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://port-80-3rebi65pw2.treehouse-app.com/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://port-80-3rebi65pw2.treehouse-app.com/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <header>
    <a href="index.html" id="logo">
      <h1>I AM MARTIN WONG|Learner</h1>
    </a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html" class="selected">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutme.html">About me</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>  
    </nav>
  </header>
  
  
  <div id="wrapper">
  <section>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="img/hongkong1.JPG">
        <img src="img/hongkong1.JPG" alt="">
        <p>Experimentation with monochrome</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="img/hongkong2.JPG">
        <img src="img/hongkong2.JPG" alt="Tai po">
        <p>Live market</p>
        </a>
      </li>
        <li>
          <a href="img/singapore1.JPG">
            <img src="img/singapore1.JPG" alt="Nearby Chinatown">
            <p>Somewhere in Chinatown, Singapore</p>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
  
<footer>© Martin Wong 2017</footer>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do You use bootstrap ? If Yes, then bootstrap add margin-bottom for every H1. Set:

```
h1{
  margin-bottom:0px !important;
}
```

PS. Do not use things like `normalize.css` ... learn Yourself.

Comment: Ive been learning on treehouse and they say to start the css page with normalize.css and then make a new css page. Is this bad? 
for example,
<link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
and below this:
<link href="css/martinCSS.css" rel=stylesheet">